# Organize files in Xcode project and get the list of folders programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsbundle

I have the following structure inside my Xcode project in resource navigator which I want to reflect inside my app.

[image]

Namely, I want to "scan" inside the "Books" folder and get an `NSArray` of all the folders in it. The next step is I want to get an `NSArray` of all the files in each folder.

So far, I've tried using anything, that's connected to `NSBundle` to get the list of folders, but this gives me wrong results:

```
NSLog(@"bundle path is %@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]);

NSLog(@"resource path is %@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]);
```

Both of these methods don't reflect the actual folder structure programmatically.

Is there any way we can do this?

Comment: The yellow (group) folders in your Xcode project have no relation at all to how the files get stored in the app's resource bundle. They all end up in the root of the app bundle.

Comment: @rmaddy if we add them as _folder references_, then how can we access the structure and the files programmatically?

Comment: If the folders are blue (folder references) in Xcode, then the folders will appear inside the app bundle. Simply use `NSFileManager` to list its contents.

Comment: First check in the physical directory in mac weather they are stored in the same structure as you have in xcode.

Comment: Or you can try to copy bundle resources with a shell script added as a build stage, might be helpful for large sets of directories and files minimising manual work of organisation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @rmaddy noted, you should actually have *blue* folders in your Xcode project and then use the `NSDirectoryEnumerator` to get a complete list of all the folders.

Here is how I've solved this:

```
NSURL *bundleURL = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Books" isDirectory:YES];

NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtURL:bundleURL includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLNameKey, NSURLIsDirectoryKey,nil] options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsSubdirectoryDescendants  errorHandler:nil];

for (NSURL *theURL in dirEnumerator){

    // Retrieve the file name. From NSURLNameKey, cached during the enumeration.
    NSString *folderName;
    [theURL getResourceValue:&folderName forKey:NSURLNameKey error:NULL];

    // Retrieve whether a directory. From NSURLIsDirectoryKey cached during the enumeration.

    NSNumber *isDirectory;
    [theURL getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:NULL];

    if([isDirectory boolValue] == YES){
        NSLog(@"Name of dir is %@", folderName);
    }
}
```